# PhpStorm and Git - Push failed - Failed with error:

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

I get this error when trying to push to my repo from PhpStorm.

I have set it up correctly I hope.

PhpStorm info
[image]

Here is the GIT test screen
[image]

And here is the GitHub test screen
[image]

But every time I try to push I get this
[image]

There is also no mention of the "error" in the terminal screen.
Any idea why this could be the case

Comment: Please check your `idea.log` for possible details (`Help | Show Log in...`)

Comment: Checked the log, can give you a few of the latest lines if it helps. Changes/Commited/Pushed 10 min after lats log file change (its closed). 
No new edit time stamp or new log file, but getting same message.

Also different now is Ive set up a ssh setup as per JebBrains specifications. Still getting same issue.

Comment: Checked the log file, but there is no "error" in the time frame. But I dont know enough about it to feel strongly that ther might be a message that suggests something was wrong.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this at all, unfortunately. This is was just a suggestion -- maybe it had some details there. If you will see no good advices here (which may happen -- considering that there is no details) .. then try https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great help from JetBrains

My Git was corrupted in some way, so I re-installed it.
Problem fixed.

Here was a similar issue
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/394